# Excel - Splitting Content Using Mid & Left Functions with Variable Length Subject & Returns

Tags: excel, function, variables, split

Splitting an outlook formatted contact in excel using Left and Mid Functions.

Use of [] shows contents of the cell...

A1 = [fname lname < email@domain.com >;]

I need to split that content into the following, getting rid of spaces, <, ;, etc.  Keep in mind, you can't use static starting or length of character numbers as all of these names, emails, domains are variable.

B1 = [fname]

C1 = [lname]

D1 = [email@domain.com]

I'm having problems with C1.  here are the functions i'm using.

For B1 = [=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)] - This grabs just the first name

For C1 = [=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(" ",A1))]  - This isn't working, its cutting off longer last names

For D1 = [=MID(A1,FIND("<",A1)+1,SEARCH(">",A1,1)+1)] - This is working fine for pulling out the email address.

Can anyone help with that function for C1?  I can't figure out how to stop it from cutting some of the last names too short.  I'm trying to set the number of characters to find the next open space " " after the last name and before the "<", but it doesn't work.

Let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way

`=REPLACE(TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("<",A1)-1)),1,FIND(" ",A1),"")`

....also does your D1 formula really work? won't it also grab the >; at the end? Try this version

`=REPLACE(TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND(">",A1)-1)),1,FIND("<",A1)+1,"")`

Answer (score 0):

The full syntax for FIND is `FIND( substring, string, [start_position] )`

So you need to FIND the 2nd blank to get the length of LName - something like

```
C1 = [=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1))]
```